# Get height of child layout (including child elements) in onCreateView of fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

The size of a layout i'm using in a fragment is always 0.

I have a fragment that includes a child-layout that looks like this:

```
 <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/animationLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="30dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp">
```

This layout has a child-layout that is defined like this:

```
  <TableLayout android:id="@+id/searchForm"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:stretchColumns="0"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

            [Some Child elements]
</TableLayout>
```

In the onCreateView of the parent fragment, the height of the layout 'searchForm' is always 0.

Even if i measure the size in

```
searchForm.post(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
        searchFormHeight = searchForm.getHeight(); //always 0
     }
}
```

the size is 0.

How can i get the size of this layout in onCreateView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i don't know what i've done wrong before, but finally following worked for me:

```
 searchForm.post(new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
            searchFormHeight = searchForm.getHeight();
         }
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a ViewTreeListener for a callback when the entire view is inflated. If I recall android waits for the entire view to be inflated at once, so even if a view is instaniated, it may not be inflated returning a height of 0.

```
searchForm.getViewTreeObserver()
     .addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
     @Override
     public boolean onPreDraw () {
        searchFormHeight = searchForm.getHeight();

        return true;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually onCreateView() process the creation of view that's why it return 0

Try following to get height, override function into fragment class

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) 
{
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    searchFormHeight = searchForm.getHeight();

}
```